# Adding column in a GeoDataFrame with the SRID of each geometry?

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I'm merging a list of shapefiles with this code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas
import geopandas
from tqdm import tqdm

folder = Path(r"read path")
shapefiles = folder.glob("PARCELA(*).SHP")
gdf = pandas.concat([
    geopandas.read_file(shp)
    for shp in tqdm(shapefiles)
]).pipe(geopandas.GeoDataFrame)
gdf.to_file(folder / r'write path')
```

The shapefile is created correctly, the problem is that I have diferents projections on some of the shapefiles i'm merging and I want to normalize them. What I thought is to add a column with the SRID of each geometry for later reproject each geometry to a unique SRID.

I know how to extract the EPSG of each geometry:

```
geom_srid_num  = gdf.crs.to_epsg()
```

But I don't know how to add a new column for each row of the concatenation shown before.

Any ideas?

Comment: It might make sense to have a property of the *original* coordinate reference (before it was altered to match the other objects), but that would need to be added before the data was all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're going to have to break up the one-liner approach you've got set up so that you can add some extra info to each `GeoDataFrame` you read in.

More importantly, I would **strongly** advise against concatenating `GeoDataFrames` that have different projections. This is because GeoPandas doesn't support a single `GeoDataFrame` having more than just one CRS, so any kind of geographic manipulation you try to perform on the concatenated `GeoDataFrame` will very likely result in some very weird results.

Instead, you can transform them all to some master CRS (say EPSG:4326) and then concatenate them all as follows:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas
import geopandas
from tqdm import tqdm

folder = Path(r"read path")
shapefiles = folder.glob("PARCELA(*).SHP")
gdf_list = []
for shp in tqdm(shapefiles):
    gdf = geopandas.read_file(shp)
    gdf['Original_File'] = str(shp)
    gdf['Original_EPSG'] = gdf.crs.to_epsg()
    gdf = gdf.to_crs('epsg:4326')
    gdf_list.append(gdf.copy())

gdf_final = pandas.concat(gdf_list, ignore_index=True)
gdf_final.to_file(folder / r'write path')
```

In the code above, the `gdf_final` variable has all the combined rows of the original  data and two extra columns: "Original_File" and "Original_EPSG", which contain, respectively, the name of the original shapefile and the EPSG code of the original shapefile.

Furthermore, the `gdf_final` variable has ALL of its geometric features in EPSG:4326 and can be properly used in geographic operations.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed :). The only error I had was a type error on the column that writes the original path of the shapefile. I just converted to str. 
  gdf['Original_File'] = str(shp).

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to accelerate this proces. Removing the "ignore_index=True" for example? or this will cause problems?

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the `str(shp)`! I've edited the code above to fix that. You can remove the `ignore_index` parameter, but that won't affect the execution speed - It will only keep the original index values of all the original shapefiles. So if you try to pull in the row with index 1, you won't just get one single row - you'll get the many rows that were indexed as 1 across all the shapefiles.

Comment: You might be able to do something about the processing speed if you try a multi-threading approach for the `for` loop above, but I have no idea of how to actually do that.